# JavaFX Application GUI Not Showing on Mac

Tags: javafx

I am trying to run JavaFX application on Mac, its running without any exceptions or error but GUI vanishes and application keep on running.

Its working fine on Windows, its working on some Mac's but having this issue with some Mac's.

Following messages are shown when the screen vanishes:

```
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x2f8a7 token 0x5bfffffffffbbe6
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: Backtrace (at 43094):
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  0   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8a730d81 CGSBacktraceCreate + 59
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  1   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8a7859f4 _ZN16CGSUpdateManager14disable_updateEv + 84
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  2   AppKit                              0x00007fff880bad15 -[NSWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush] + 127
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  3   AppKit                              0x00007fff880b995a -[NSView(NSInternal) geometryInWindowDidChange] + 185
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  4   AppKit                              0x00007fff880b9581 -[NSView _invalidateFocus] + 437
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8814b5a5 -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:] + 2263
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8814a51d -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] + 2562
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  7   AppKit                              0x00007fff882e2e18 -[NSMoveHelper _stopAnimation] + 517
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff882ddec9 -[NSMoveHelper _doAnimation] + 1756
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff882ff6d6 -[NSMoveHelper _resizeWindow:toFrame:display:] + 419
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff88207dd9 -[NSWindow setFrame:display:animate:] + 1495
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff882fe6e3 -[NSWindow zoom:] + 808
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  12  libglass.dylib                      0x0000000126fe0de3 Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacWindow__1maximize + 499
Aug  4 13:07:14 Jiveshs-MacBook-Pro.local java[9832] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  13  ???                                 0x0000000110f7e954 0x0 + 4579649876
```

--I think that there is some problem with graphic driver as most of them have Intel HD 4000 series.

Comment: I have such kind of trouble. Did you solve them?

Comment: yes, this was the issue with this particular graphic driver and java version. It worked fine with same series if I updated my Java version.

Comment: could it be a duplicate of the following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776190/cannot-launch-a-javafx-application-on-macos-using-java-8/56817445#56817445

Comment: No... Its a different issue.