# Running JavaFX on MacOs

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm using IntelliJ and I want to run an old JavaFX project I used to run in Linux, I've imported the libraries and I've used the vm parameters

`--module-path /Users/frenk/Desktop/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

but I keep receiving the same error

`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

all the answers I've seen are related to the vm params so I can't figure out what might be the problem, I'm using java 16 as runtime and macOS big sur

Comment: FYI, both Azul Systems and  BellSoft both offer versions of their OpenJDK builds that include the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries. Replacing your JDK with one of those may be convenient.

Comment: If you use Java with version more than 10, you must add the necessary jars from https://openjfx.io/ . You can take a look also at some related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776190/cannot-launch-a-javafx-application-on-macos-using-java-8

Comment: I've included the BellSoft JDK, Intellij recognise the import but when I try to build the project it says ```java: package javafx.fxml does not exist``` and the same for every JavaFX element

Comment: You may need to enable `Desktop` access in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Security`; I simply moved the SDK to `/Users/Shared`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a workaround, I created a new JavaFX project with IntelliJ using the BellSoft SDK, then I copied the content inside my old `src` folder to the new one, everything works so I'm ok with that.

Stil don't know why the original project isn't running maybe some reference to the oldest library I was using when I wrote the program in Linux